# How to Execute sql queries in Apache Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am very new to **Apache Spark**.

I have already configured  spark 2.0.2 on my local windows machine.
I have done with "word count" example with spark.

Now, I have the problem in executing the SQL Queries.
I have searched for the same , but not getting proper guidance .

Comment: So, what's your problem? You're getting some error?

Comment: error: not found: value sqlContext

Comment: I am getting the above exception while running the below command

Comment: val dataframe_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "mydb").option("user", "root").option("password", "").load()

Comment: not sure why it's down voted. I find this question helpful!

Answer (score 15):

So you need to do these things to get it done ,

In Spark 2.0.2 we have SparkSession which contains SparkContext instance as well as sqlContext instance.

Hence the steps would be :

**Step 1:** Create SparkSession

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("MyApp").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

**Step 2:** Load from the database in your case Mysql.

```
val loadedData=spark
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase")
      .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
      .option("mytable", "mydatabase")
      .option("user", "root")
      .option("password", "toor")
      .load().createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
```

**Step 3:** Now you can run your SqlQuery just like you do in SqlDatabase.

```
val dataFrame=spark.sql("Select * from mytable")
dataFrame.show()
```

P.S: It would be better if you use DataFrame Api's or even better if DataSet Api's , but for those you need to go through the documentation.

Link to Documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Comment: Could you add some arguments behind your suggestion to use the Dataset API? Otherwise the statement is just an opinion and should be ignored. Keep in mind that the SQL API is usually ahead (e.g. many higher order functions were introduced in Spark SQL 2.4, but they were not available to the Dataset API).

Comment: Assuming this way, the query will be fired from the driver, right? Also, the results will be loaded into the driver's memory, correct?

Answer (score 9):

In Spark 2.x you no longer reference `sqlContext`, but rather `spark`, so you need to do:

```
spark
  .read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb")
  .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .option("dbtable", "mydb")
  .option("user", "root")
  .option("password", "")
  .load()
```

Comment: Assuming this way, the query will be fired from the driver, right? Also, the results will be loaded into the driver's memory, correct?

Comment: No, not correct. Data will be loaded by workers into worker memory as always. But I believe there are also settings for how many concurrent connections it should use.

Answer (score 2):

You should have your Spark DataFrame.
**Create a TempView out of DataFrame**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("dftable")
dfsql = sc.sql("select * from dftable")
```

**You can use long queries in statement format:**

```
sql_statement = """
select sensorid, objecttemp_c,
year(DateTime) as year_value,
month(DateTime) as month_value,
day(DateTime) as day_value,
hour(DateTime) as hour_value
from dftable
order by 1 desc
"""

dfsql = sc.sql(sql_statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its rather simple now in spark to do SQL queries.
You can do SQL on dataframes as pointed out by others but the questions is really how to do SQL.

`spark.sql("SHOW TABLES;")`
that's it.

Comment: With spark in ASA (Azure Synapse Analytics), there is "lazy loading" ... so `spark.sql` creates the dataframe, but does not yet execute.  Execution waits until there's an output action.  Does `spark.sql` immediately execute, in other implementations of spark?

Comment: spark.sql executes SQL. I believe the intention is to use it over transformations in python.  If you want to do the transformations in python on dataframes then it's going to use lazy evaluation. But if you use SQL and join a few tables, do some calls, and write to a table that's done in lazy eval.. but it has an action so its executed.  SQL is declarative python is not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I guess you meant that doing it in SQL, it would have eager eval?  I got the point in any case.

Comment: SQL will still execute in lazy evaluation. Spark will always. What you won't have is the chance to notice the lazy evaluation since you are including an action. FULL SQL is not procedural. If I write create this table, then it does it.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  By "full sql", are you including what runs in an azure synapse analytics notebook cell, that starts with `%%sql`?  Because my experience is that those `%%sql` cells execute immediately -- eager eval -- even if the notebook as a whole, is set to pyspark.

Comment: I have not used azure synapse notebooks much but I assume they are the same as spark.sql and a databricks notebook with a SQL magic cell. In that case the whole cell is treated as doing transformations, but always have an action. This is how SQL works. within the cell its doing lazy transformations. Again it must follow this formula since Spark only doing lazy eval and SQL and dataframe API both get converted to the exact same thing by the catalyst optimizer. Again SQL is non procedural so you define what you want in the end (the action) and it "figures out what to do" (the transformations).

Answer (score 0):

Executing SQL Queries using spark.sql() or dataset API will compile to exactly same code by the catayst optimiser at compile time and AQE at runtime.
You can choose whatever you are comfortable.