# PySpark: group by between two dates

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to count the number of times the field "measure" has the value "M" between date 1 and date 2 for each pair id and id_2

** date 1 is when the measure is taken and date 2 is date 1 - 5 days, since 5 days is the period on which we want to count the number of measures taken.

```
|      date 1|      date 2|     id        |        id_2    |    measure|
+----------  +----------  +---------------+----------------+-----------+
|2016-10-25  |2016-10-20  |              1|               1|          M|
|2016-10-26  |2016-10-21  |              1|               5|           |
|2016-10-22  |2016-10-17  |              1|               1|          M|
|2016-10-30  |2016-10-25  |              1|               2|          M|
|2016-10-22  |2016-10-17  |              2|               1|          M|
|2016-10-26  |2016-10-21  |              2|               2|           |
|2016-10-18  |2016-10-13  |              2|               5|          M|
|2016-10-25  |2016-10-20  |              2|               1|           |
+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
```

And the desired output would be:

```
|     date 1|      date 2|     id        |        id_2    |    measure| count
+---------- +----------  +---------------+----------------+-----------+-----+
|2016-10-25 |2016-10-20  |              1|               1|          M|    1|
|2016-10-26 |2016-10-21  |              1|               5|           |    0|
|2016-10-22 |2016-10-17  |              1|               1|          M|    0|
|2016-10-30 |2016-10-25  |              1|               2|          M|    0|
|2016-10-22 |2016-10-17  |              2|               1|          M|    0|
|2016-10-26 |2016-10-21  |              2|               2|           |    0|
|2016-10-18 |2016-10-13  |              2|               5|          M|    0|
|2016-10-25 |2016-10-20  |              2|               1|           |    1|
+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+----------+-----+
```

I believe that windows might be helpful but I am not sure how to apply them to this problem. Previously I have solved this kind of problem with a subquery, but in Pyspark they cannot be applied.

The query I have previously used is:

```
SELECT a.date1,
a.date2,
a.id,
a.id_2,
a.measure,
(select count(data.[id]) as CountMeasure 
    from dataOrigin data 
    where data.id = a.id 
        and data.id_2 = a.id_2 and measure = 'M'
        and datos.date1 > date2 and datos.date1 < a.date1) as count


FROM dataOrigin a
```

If more info is needed please let me know

Thank you every body!

Comment: *"Previously I have solved this kind of problem with a subquery, but in Pyspark they cannot be applied"* - why can't subqueries be applied? If you have the logic SQL, can you [edit] your question and add it?

Comment: There you have the query I used. When I try to implement this on Pyspark with SQLContext I get an error.

Comment: What's the error you get? Please include that as well. One thing I see is that you are aliasing your subquery as `count` and then you also use the `count()` function - try renaming that subquery as something else. Also I think it should be `data.id`, not `data.[id]`.

Comment: It is not the query itself because I have tried it at small scale with SQL and it works just fine, it is that pyspark does not allow me to perform that operation

Comment: You can run queries in [tag:pyspark-sql]. Take a look at [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866970/5858851) for example.