# Prefixing field names in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I hope you can help!

I've made the below to convert SQL to PySpark code. All of it works perfectly and produces the output that i've pasted below the code

The only bit that is a problem is:

```
.filter(((( dt == 20181211))&(hour == 13 )|( hour == 14)))
```

Here, each field needs to be prefixed by df1. - so for example, df1.dt.

I can't think of a sensible way to do this - I was thinking about typing df1. after every bracket, but where we have ((( that would not work.

Any ideas???

```
#
#
# INPUTS
#
#
query = 'select dt, hour, count(imsi), sum(service_dl_bytes), sum(service_ul_bytes), count(msisdn)'
from_statement = 'from udsapp.dpi_datasum'
where = '((where dt = 20181211)) and (hour = 13 or hour = 14)'
#
#
#OUTPUTS
#
#
#split items in the query at the comma
result = [x.strip() for x in query.split(',')]

all_and = []
all_or = []
features = []
sums = []
sum_fields = []
count_fields = []
counts = []

#extract features - if sum / count, then add to their own lists
#if not sum or count, then add to features list
for x in result:
  if 'sum' in x:
    sums.append(x)
  elif 'count' in x:
    counts.append(x)
  else:
    if 'select' in x:
      features.append(x.replace('select', '').strip())
    else:
      features.append(x.replace('select', '').strip())
#add quotes around each of the items in features list & make single string
extracted_features = ', '.join('\'{0}\''.format(x) for x in features)

#add '' around from db
froms = "'" + from_statement + "'"
#remove from & trim, to leave only db & table names
if 'from' in froms:
  new_from = froms.replace('from' , '').strip()

#extract sum fields for agg - split at the brackets to extract only field names
for x in sums:
  if '(' in x:
    z = x.split('(', 1)[-1]
    q = z.split(')', 1)[0]
    sum_fields.append(q)
#Add quotes around each of the sum fields & add to single string
extracted_sums = ', '.join('\'{0}\''.format(x) for x in sum_fields)

#extract count fields for agg - split at the brackets to extract only field names
for x in counts:
  if '(' in x:
    z = x.split('(', 1)[-1]
    q = z.split(')', 1)[0]
    count_fields.append(q)
#Add quotes around each of the count fields & add to single string
extracted_counts = ', '.join('\'{0}\''.format(x) for x in count_fields)

####Extract where attributes
if 'or' in where:
  where = where.replace(') or (', ')|(')
  where = where.replace(')or(', ')|(')
  where = where.replace('or', ')|(')
if 'and' in where:
  where = where.replace(') and (', ')&(')
  where = where.replace(')and(', ')&(')
  where = where.replace('and', ')&(')
if 'where' in where:
  where = where.replace('where', '').strip()
if '=' in where:
  where = where.replace('=', '==')

#####################################################
print("from pyspark.sql import SparkSession")
print("import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc")
print("import argparse, sys")
print("from pyspark.sql import *")
print("from pyspark.sql.functions import *")
print("from datetime import datetime")
#create a context that supports hive
print("def create_session(appname):")
print("    spark_session = SparkSession\\")
print("        .builder\\")
print("        .appName(appname)\\")
print("        .master('yarn')\\")
print("        .config(\"hive.metastore.uris\",thrift://uds-far-mn1.dab.02.net:9083\").enableHiveSupport()\\")
print("        .getOrCreate()")
print("    return spark_session")

### START MAIN ###
print("if __name__ == '__main__':")
print("    spark_session = create_session('myspark)")
print("    df1 = spark_session.table(" + new_from.replace(' ', '').strip() + ")")
print("    df_agg = df1\\")
print("       .coalesce(1000)\\")

# PRINT WHERE STATEMENT
print("       .filter((" + where + "))\\")

# PRINT INITIAL SELECT STATEMENT - Depending on whether there are counts or sums, this will be a different select statement 
if len(sums) and len(counts) == 0:
  print("       .select(" + extracted_features + ")\\")
elif len(sums) ==0 and len(counts) > 0:
  print("       .select(" + extracted_features + "," + extracted_counts + ")\\")
elif len(sums) > 0 and len(counts) == 0:
  print("       .select(" + extracted_features + "," + extracted_sums + ")\\")
elif len(sums) > 0 and len(counts) > 0:
  print("       .select(" + extracted_features + "," + extracted_sums + "," + extracted_counts + ")\\")

##### PRINT AGGREGATIONS WITH CORRECT FORMATTING
sum_list = extracted_sums.split(",")
count_list = extracted_counts.split(",")

#If we have sums and counts, then print the agg statements for all. When we reach the final value in the list, don't add the training comma and slash
if len(sums) and len(counts) > 0:
    print("       .groupBy(" + extracted_features + ")\\")
    print("       .agg(")

    for x in sum_list:
      print("            sqlfunc.sum(df1." + x.replace('\'', '').replace(' ', '').strip() + ").alias(" + x + "),\\")

    for x in count_list:
      if x != count_list[len(count_list)-1]:
        print("            sqlfunc.count(df1." + x.replace('\'', '').replace(' ', '').strip() + ").alias(" + x + "),\\")
      else:
        print("            sqlfunc.count(df1." + x.replace('\'', '').replace(' ', '').strip() + ").alias(" + x + ")")

#If we have sums & no counts, then print the agg statements for all sums. When we reach the final value in the list, don't add the training comma and slash
if len(sums) > 0 and len(counts) == 0:
    print("       .groupBy(" + extracted_features + ")\\")
    print("       .agg(")

    for x in sum_list:
      if x != sum_list[len(sum_list)-1]:
        print("            sqlfunc.sum(df1." + x.replace('\'', '').replace(' ', '').strip() + ").alias(" + x+ "),\\")
      else:
        print("            sqlfunc.sum(df1." + x.replace('\'', '').replace(' ', '').strip() + ").alias(" + x+ ")")      

#If we have counts and no sums, then print the agg statements for all counts. When we reach the final value in the list, don't add the training comma and slash
if len(counts) > 0 and len(sums) == 0:
    print("       .groupBy(" + extracted_features + ")\\")
    print("       .agg(")

    for x in count_list:
      if x != count_list[len(count_list)-1]:
        print("            sqlfunc.count(df1." + x.replace('\'', '').replace(' ', '').strip() + ").alias(" + x + "),\\")
      else:
        print("            sqlfunc.count(df1." + x.replace('\'', '').replace(' ', '').strip() + ").alias(" + x + ")")  

#only print the closing brackets if we have aggregations
if len(counts) >0 or len(sums) >0:
  print("            )\\")

# PRINT THE FINAL SELECT
if len(sums) and len(counts) == 0:
  print("       .select(" + extracted_features + ")")
elif len(sums) ==0 and len(counts) > 0:
  print("       .select(" + extracted_features + "," + extracted_counts + ")")
elif len(sums) > 0 and len(counts) == 0:
  print("       .select(" + extracted_features + "," + extracted_sums + ")")
elif len(sums) > 0 and len(counts) > 0:
  print("       .select(" + extracted_features + "," + extracted_sums + "," + extracted_counts + ")")
print("df_agg.createOrReplaceTempView(\"temporarytable\")")
print("finaldf = spark_session.sql(\"INSERT INTO table . select * from temporarytable\")")
```

**OUTPUT CODE**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
import argparse, sys
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime
def create_session(appname):
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName(appname)\
        .master('yarn')\
        .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://uds-far-mn1.dab.02.net:9083").enableHiveSupport()\
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark_session
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark_session = create_session('myspark')
    df1 = spark_session.table('udsapp.dpi_datasum')
    df_agg = df1\
       .coalesce(1000)\
       .filter(((( dt == 20181211))&(hour == 13 )|( hour == 14)))\
       .select('dt', 'hour','service_dl_bytes', 'service_ul_bytes','imsi', 'msisdn')\
       .groupBy('dt', 'hour')\
       .agg(
            sqlfunc.sum(df1.service_dl_bytes).alias('service_dl_bytes'),\
            sqlfunc.sum(df1.service_ul_bytes).alias( 'service_ul_bytes'),\
            sqlfunc.count(df1.imsi).alias('imsi'),\
            sqlfunc.count(df1.msisdn).alias( 'msisdn')
            )\
       .select('dt', 'hour','service_dl_bytes', 'service_ul_bytes','imsi', 'msisdn')
df_agg.createOrReplaceTempView("temporarytable")
finaldf = spark_session.sql("INSERT INTO table . select * from temporarytable")
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just execute the query?

Comment: It's running against a 6PB dataset and so using spark is necessary

Comment: Sure but you can execute the query on spark using sparksql. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841900/how-to-execute-sql-queries-in-apache-spark) for example.